# How can I subtract hours and minutes from a HH:MM time string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I have a string `realTime = 10:15` and i have subtract `1:20` means(one hours twenty minutes) from string realTime .

output should be = 8:55.

I am trying something with moment

```
moment().subtract(realTime , '1:20');
```

But it's not working, Help me to find the solution. 
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's

```
moment(realTime, 'HH:mm').subtract(80, 'minutes');
```

Or, alternatively, you can use `moment.duration`

```
var realTime = '10:15';
var duration = moment.duration({hours: 1, minutes: 20})
var sub = moment(realTime, 'HH:mm').subtract(duration).format();
```